# jquery load with variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

With the following script I load a HTML document into a div-container and show it.
With the variable "x" I avoid that the document is reloaded with every click on the button.

The function to hide the container is missing here, as it has nothing to do with my question.

```
x = 0;
$('.button').click(function () {
    if (x == 0){
        $('.box').load('article.html', function () {
            x = 1;
            $('.box').fadeIn();
        });
    }else{
        $('.box').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

My question is, how do I have to change the script, if I have more buttons that load different documents?

The variable "x" has to work individually for all the buttons. Is there something like "this.variable" or am I wrong and I have to come up with something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the document to load in a data attribute. For example:

```
<span class="button" data-doc="article.html">Load article</span>
```

Then:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $box = $('.box'),
        loaded = $this.data('loaded'),
        doc;

    if (loaded) { 
        $box.fadeIn();
        return; 
    }

    doc = $this.data('doc');

    $box.load(doc, function () {
        // mark it as being loaded
        $this.data('loaded', true);
        $box.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I've never worked with the data attribute so far.

Comment: you're welcome! I've found it to be very handy. jQuery will even deserialize json that you put in there ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/78nVd/)).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery one() event handler you only use an event handler once.

```
$('.button').one('click', function () {
    $('.box').load('article.html');
});
$('.button').click(function () {
   $('.box').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Didn't know there is one() in jquery. It's interesting but I think in my case it's not the right choice because I won't be able to load the content of button 1 again after I clicked on another button and the box contains other content.